# Html data in comma separated value to python list

Tags: python, html

I want to create a html form where the user can enter numbers in a comma separated format and I want to store them as a list in a python variable which can be used in a function.

For example, the 2 fields in the html form would be:

```
Enter range of number: 1000-2000,2500-2600, 4000-4100

Enter random numbers: 1, 3, 4, 6, 100, 128, 266
```

How can python store the html form input as

```
x = ['1000-2000', '2500-2600', '4000-4100']
y = ['1', '3', '4', '6', '100', '128', '266']
```

I'm new in programming and would much appreciate some help on this please.

The requirement is the user can copy paste the numbers in a comma separated format and then allow the python script to use them as input.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking for [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) and [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip);

```
In [5]: s = '1000-2000,2500-2600, 4000-4100'

In [6]: [a.strip() for a in s.split(',')]
Out[6]: ['1000-2000', '2500-2600', '4000-4100']
```

Comment: Many thanks for that, it does solve my problem. However to make the code more efficient what would you suggest to do.

Comment: Ideally, it would be better to have all the numbers in 1 line

x = ['1000-2000', '2500-2600', '4000-4100']
y = ['1', '3', '4', '6', '100', '128', '266']

My program does the following in simplest terms..

a, b = x.split("-")
print(a,b)
else
print(y)

It would have been better to have just one list and depending if a range is entered or not, print start range, end range and individual number.